# How to assign current page url to hidden field

Tags: marketo

I am trying to assign the current page's url to a hidden form field.

Is there any way to do this ?

For the hidden field's Autofill behaviour, you can only get value from the following:

Default Value, URL Parameter,  Cookie Value, Referrer Parameter

However I am using rest urls, therefore will not have parameters, but would like to save the entire url to the hidden field

thanks in advance

Sum

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can set values on hidden fields on Marketo form:

```
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjst.marketo.com", "785-UHP-775", 1057, function (form) { 
    // Set values for the hidden fields, "userIsAwesome" and "enrollDate"
    // Note that these fields were configured in the form editor as hidden fields already
    form.vals({"userIsAwesome":"true", "enrollDate":"2014-01-01"});
});
```

See example: http://developers.marketo.com/assets/Forms2DevExamples/example7.html

Source: http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/