# how can I add scripts to pages or forms

Tags: marketo

is it possible to scripts, preferably Jquery, to forms

I tried to add it to the Munchkin tracking script but that field is read only

is there another option for adding scripts to forms

thanks

Sum

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to check the documentation on http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/forms-2-0/
and
http://developers.marketo.com/blog/?s=form

Marketo Forms support some customization using simple JS or jQuery.

Do you have any specific customization in mind?

Comment: you answered my question in a related topic

Comment: thanks 
you answered my question in a related question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012234/how-to-assign-current-page-url-to-hidden-field/35018111#35018111